# Delete my careers account

Tags: support, jobs, user-accounts

I have an existing Careers 2.0 account that I created years ago with a myOpenID login.
In the process of trying to move that to a StackExchange login, I accidentally created a **new** Careers account with the Stack login.
I'd like to delete the 2nd account (Stack login) and associate my 1st account with the Stack login instead.

Thank you.

Existing account: (myOpenID)
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/47068

Accidental account: (StackExchange)
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/101704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I don't think you accidentally created a new account. From what I can tell you actually added the new Stack login to your existing account. So the good news is that you're all set! Either login you use will take you to the same account.